# Ubuntu screen turns black after "recovering journal" and purple screen in recovery blacks out

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, fsck, recovery-mode

One day, I was powering off my PC to check the thermal paste because it was getting hot. I turned it back on, and now the screen momentarily says "recovering journal" then turns black.

I tried getting into GRUB. I boot Kernel 5.15.0-50-generic in Recovery mode. It shows the purple options for a few seconds, then the screen turns black.

Booting in 5.15.0-43-generic Recovery mode worked. Interestingly, after trying several options, I selected boot normally, and it did. Working desktop. But as soon as I reboot, black screen again.

I tried using Ubuntu live USB to run fsck, it says `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is fine. In 5.15.0-43-generic Recovery, fsck mode, I get this:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is mounted.
```

This is not dual boot. I swear this exact same thing eventually happened to me when I installed Manjaro on a different SSD. *Any suggestions?*

EDIT: I think it might have something to do with the NVIDIA drivers. When I boot in 5.15.0-43-generic Recovery mode, it uses the mesa drivers.

Comment: You knocked something lose or damaged something when working with the hardware?

Comment: If I did, how can it boot normally in backup safe mode? I think it might have something to do with the NVIDIA drivers.